# Error handling truncate number in power automate desktop where you have excels with different numbers

Tags: power-automate-desktop

I am trying to perform Reconciliation using power automate Desktop, and I am facing an issue when looping trough two different excels with a different number of rows.

I am using For each loop to get the variables in the first excel and a second for each loop to loop through the second excel, but when the first excel has more rows than the second excel, I get an exception when trying to truncate the number and the process stops, and does not proceed.

Is there a better way to do recon in power automate Desktop, or how can I make the process to not stop after encountering this exception.

Below is an image of the process.
[image]

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap that line in a 'On Error Block' and add a rule inside the error block to set the truncated value to 0.

Copy the text blow into Power Automate Desktop to see the settings.

```
BLOCK truncateError
ON BLOCK ERROR all
SET TruncatedValue TO 0
NEXT ACTION
END
    Variables.TruncateNumber.GetIntegerPart Number: $'''text throws an error (or can be variable)''' Result=> TruncatedValue
END
```

It should look something like this when you edit the function:

[image: error block settings]

The flow:

[image: flow]

Variable value:

[image: variable]